# Grid Recursion Not Functioning

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to solve a problem on Project Euler (Project 16) using grid recursion and it isn't working out so well - I'm just ending up with what seems like an infinite loop. The goal is to count how many routes you can take to get from the top left of a 20x20 grid to the bottom right of the grid, so I start from the origin and placed a number in myGrid[20][20] that indicates it's at the bottom right corner.

```
private static int[][] myGrid;

public static int numRoutes(int x, int y){
    if (x < 0 || x >= 20 || y < 0 || y>= 20){
        return 0;
    }
    if (myGrid[x][y] == 1){
        return 1;
    }
    int count = 0;
    count += numRoutes(x+1, y);
    count += numRoutes(x, y+1);
    return count;
}

public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception{
    myGrid = new int[21][21];
    for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++){
        Arrays.fill(myGrid[i], 0);
    }
    myGrid[20][20] = 1;
    int num = numRoutes(0,0);
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

This comprises most of my recursion, and I think that I have all of the appropriate base cases. Any thoughts on what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is not going into an infinite loop. It just has so many options that it looks like that...
To test it, just reduce the array size to `5X5`.... And you will see that it ends...

That being said, your result will always be `0` because of a bug...

```
if (x < 0 || x >= 20 || y < 0 || y>= 20){
```

should be

```
if (x < 0 || x > 20 || y < 0 || y > 20){
```

instead...

Also, I don't think this algorithm gives you the count of all the paths between 2 points... It just gives you the count of all the **shortest** paths... Since the flow goes only from `top to bottom` and `left to right`... Not in other direction...

Comment: Thank you for the catch, of course >= 20 would return 0 all the time. And yes, the question stated that you can only go right or down, so it should be okay! Although, how long is it expected to take? I feel as if I've waited easily 3 or 4 minutes at a time.

Comment: The count increases exponentially with the array size... So it will be huge... For debugging sake, just reduce the size of array and increase it gradually... You will see the difference...